# Sci fi short story that contains the line "My JJ's are melting!"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to recall a short story from the 80's that, as I think back, seems prescient of several computing technologies we're currently using.

There was an AI capable of self-improvement and a human friend, possibly the engineer. The talking computer personality may have been based on [FPGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-programmable_gate_array). He was definitely built using something called a "***J***osephson **J**unction" because one of the emotional parts had him pleading

> ***"Hurry, my JJ's are melting"***

as parts of his mind were beginning to permanently fail.

Comment: What the heck is this Quag Keep/Green Magic thing and what does it have to do with the question?

Comment: They're other stories I've tracked down later.

Comment: Try to include as little noise as possible in these sorts of questions. You don't want someone to waste a minute of their research time looking up stuff that doesn't actually relate to your story.

Comment: 'Josephson junction' is a quantum mechanical device, which is made of two superconducting electrodes separated by a barrier. Was going to be the next big thing in computers.

Comment: Ah yes, I've edited away the original "Jameson Junction".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**“M.A.C. Gate: The Manners of Logic”** by **Ralph Mylius**. It was featured in **[Softalk magazine, February 1983](https://archive.org/details/softalkv3n06feb1983/page/238)**, p. 238.

- **Self-improving AI with human (engineer?) friend**

The computer is pretty independent from human input. He and his human partner are some sort of detectives?

> I had just started working on the FedLect case for Sam when it
>   happened. Sam's my partner. Actually he built me to help him with his
>   work, but I like to think that we operate as a team. Sam handles the
>   physical side of the business while I do most of the legwork. It's an
>   arrangement that has worked out well over the years.

- **Computer based on field-programmable gate array**

There's *something* about gates, not sure if it's related at all to FPGAs.

> My name is M.A.C. Gate. Sam gained international recognition as a
>   computer genius after he built me: the world's largest Multiple Access
>   Cryogenic Gate.

- **“Hurry, my JJ's are melting!”**

Close, but not quite.

> ”Shirley!" I screamed in ultrafast machine code. "Shunt the auxiliary cooling capacity to my J-Js! Hurry!"

Probably mixed up with a similar quote at the beginning:

> I knew I had been drugged the minute I came to. Shirley was screaming,
>   "Your J-Js are hot! Your J-Js are hot!"

As a bonus, I've found a few more stories featuring the same characters:

- "The Microscopic Landau" ([Softalk, June 1983](https://archive.org/details/softalkv3n10jun1983/page/270))
- "Fat Men Can Not Jump Down Chimneys" ([Softalk, December 1983](https://archive.org/details/softalkv4n04dec1983/page/403))
- "A Question of Musique Concrete" ([Softalk, June 1984](https://archive.org/details/softalkv4n10jun1984/page/122)) (It's the first of three parts, but I couldn't locate the other two.)

I don't know if there are more.

Comment: This is absolutely it. I'd given up hope. Thank you so much, and bonus thanks for the bonus links.